# There is some method for prevent multi-device login on Playfab?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, playfab

Are there some method to prevent multi-device login using Playfab?

I have a card game with Playfab authentication. I must have a login control for cheaters, I would like to have only one login for each player and for each of their device, if a user login with a new device, the old device must be logged out automatically.

I try to change the session ticket or entity ticket at runtime in my c# code but I read in another post that Playfab is designed for multi-device login, in fact there isn't any function to change the session or entity ticket.

I saw somebody using CloudScript, but I don't know how it works and I don't know if it is heavy to do this.

Answer (score 0):

A possible option could be to execute a custom cloudscript function on game startup to save on Player Data the current deviceId. Every request will have to be validated using this "token", so client will have to pass this kind of information at every call.

If deviceId matches with the one saved on server, execution continues smoothly, otherwise an error should be passed as response to the client. This error can be used to show a popup on client to inform user for example.

At every login, deviceId is updated on PlayerData. In this way, you know it is read on every request, but written only once (on game startup). Also, only the last logged will be able to get server data. Other devices won't be able to get proper responses from server until the app is rebooted.